# What is more effective, a huge condition, or a huge array?

Tags: java, android, performance

In my app, i have two Fragments of which each one has a tridimensional array that stores 2160 variables, of which 720 it's float and 1440 it's integer.

I have two options:
1 - Continue with this huge tridimensional array.
2 - Or do a huge Condition.

My concern is about the application's performance on the user's mobile phone. Which would consume less time? Is the memory that this array would use high enough to affect fragment loading?

**NOTES**

- In my app, all this variables it's a constant values.
- The user will answer a series of questions to in the end display some variables.
- There are three issues:

  1. Has 6 options
  2. Has 15 options
  3. Has 8 options

But i have 3 series of this questions, in one of them i display float variables. And in the other two, I display integer variables.

Actually, it's my code. `RESULTS_ARRAY[][][]` it's a big tridimensional array, i just made a part of the code, the part dealing with the 720 float values.

```
switch (rewardSelected) {
     case 0:
          int count = 0;
          while (count < 6) {
          if(typePack == count) {
               int count2 = 0;
               while(count2 < 15) {
                    if(spinnerSelected == count2) {
                         int count3 = 0;
                         while(count3 < 8) {
                              float percent = Float.parseFloat(editTextPercent.getText().toString());
                              float withPercentApplied = (RESULTS_ARRAY[count][count3][count2] * percent) / 130;
                              if(checkFivePercent.isChecked()) {
                                   float resultFinal = ((withPercentApplied*5) / 100) + withPercentApplied;
                                   textViewResults.get(count3).setText(String.valueOf(resultFinal));
                              } else {
                                   textViewResults.get(count3).setText(String.valueOf(withPercentApplied));
                              }
                              count3++;
                         }
                    }
                    count2++;
               }
          }
          count++;
     }
          break;
     case 1:
          break;
     case 2:
          break;
}
```

Comment: by huge condition you mean a huge `if` clause?

Comment: @nandsito i would use `switch`

Comment: What are you doing? You have 2k variables in a 3d array, fine. What's the logic you're trying to optimize?

Comment: @arcy post updated

Comment: An array of 2160 variables is not that huge nowadays, is there any performance leaks when you tried to implement it?

Comment: Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Posting some actual code would probably help us understand what the issue is.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb I did not realize much difference in my cellphone, but i'm thinking in other cellphones that will use my app.

Comment: @lucasvw post updated

Comment: What you need is a config file. Your variables are constant values. I would put them in a file: json, xml

Comment: @efekctive as well?

Comment: @efekctive: exactly, an XY Problem -- he needs to re-think his approach completely.

Comment: I meant put the constant values in a file, say json. Then when deserializing , say json, the condition checking is greatly simplified. If this works, I will post it as answer. Consider when to read the file. It would not be cheap

Comment: hahaha this really seems a XY problem. Sorry, i'm new in the code world. But i think that this config file can resolve my problem, how i can do it?

Comment: Yes xy. But sometimes one needs another set of eyes

Comment: @efekctive Yes, can you help me in these config file?

Comment: Not enough time now to post the code but research json. Its helper libraries usually read files into key/value maps

Comment: Ok, thank you very much

Comment: Beyond that: you want to read about "Single Layer of Abstraction" principle; for example by looking into "Clean Code" by Robert Martin. Your code could benefit from that. Greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness sake, this is all you would need.

```
package so;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class SOCLass{

     JsonElement job;

     SOCLass(){
         try {
            job = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("JSON FILE"));
        } catch (JsonIOException | JsonSyntaxException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     boolean isValuePresent(final String v){
         return job.getAsJsonObject().get(v) != null;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
         SOCLass so = new SOCLass();
         System.out.println("Is present? " + so.isValuePresent("NO"));
     }

}
```

**EDIT**

Array contents in a json file:

```
{
  "key" : null,
  "key1" : null
}
```

If you only care about the constant values/tags. Then you could associate a real value with its key

Comment: Where i put my array? And how to read them in my class? Sorry i never used it.